# Google Chart BarChart onmouseover

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bar-chart, onmouseover

I am trying to add an listener on a "onmouseover" event on a Google BarChart, but cannot get it to work. I want to use the "mouseover"-element to make a ajax call...(a snippet of my code):

```
dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataRaw, false); 
            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("successChart"));

            //Setting options for the chart
            var options = {}....;

            chart.draw(dataTable, options);
            // Add actionlistener
            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', onmouseoverHandler);

 function onmouseoverHandler() {

                var selectedItem = chartGennemført.getSelection()[0]; // gets the value the vAxis
            }
```

The "select" handler is working fine (not shown in code), but not "onmouseover". How do I add the onmouseoverHandler ...Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

event listeners need to be added to the chart **before** the chart is drawn

also, the `'onmouseover'` event will pass the row and column as arguments to the listener function

and, `getSelection` returns an array, both when a chart element is selected **and** unselected,
need to check the length of the array before trying to access the contents...

this will fail when a bar is **unselected**

```
getSelection()[0]
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var dataRaw = [
    ['x', 'y'],
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2],
    [3, 3],
    [4, 4],
    [5, 5]
  ];

  dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataRaw, false);
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("successChart"));

  var options = {};

  // Add actionlistener
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', onmouseoverHandler);

  chart.draw(dataTable, options);

  function onmouseoverHandler(properties) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(properties));
  }

  function selectHandler() {
    var selectedItem = chart.getSelection();
    if (selectedItem.length > 0) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedItem[0]));
    } else {
      console.log('nothing selected');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="successChart"></div>
```