# Google table - get selected row

Tags: javascript, events, google-visualization

I have a table with 3 columns: Id, name, address. I want to get the Id from the selected row in the table. Cannot get it to work... Anyone?

```
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataRaw, false);
            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('successTable'));
            //Css
            var cssClassNames = {
                'headerRow': 'cssHeaderRow',
                'tableRow': 'cssTableRow',
                'oddTableRow': 'cssOddTableRow',
                'selectedTableRow': 'cssSelectedTableRow',
                'hoverTableRow': 'cssHoverTableRow',
                'headerCell': 'cssHeaderCellSmall',
                'tableCell': 'cssTableCellSmall',
                'rowNumberCell': 'cssRowNumberCell'
            };
            var options = {

                cssClassNames: cssClassNames,
                allowHtml: true,
                title: "Success",

            };


            table.draw(data, options);
            google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', selectHandler);
```

I have tried:

```
 function selectHandler() {
                var sel = table.getSelection();}
```

And other stuff, but no luck...

Comment: as I stated in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51748143/5090771), you must assign the event listener, before drawing the chart...

Comment: Tank you :) Works :) But now I got another problem - when I select the same row two times I get an error: The property "row" is undefined or null....What to do ? I use: var selectedItem = data.getValue(table.getselection()[0].row,0)

Comment: again, check the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51748143/5090771), the select event fires when something is selected and __unselected__, so you need to check the length of the selection array before trying to access the contents...